# Understanding a theorem on a holomorphic function or series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, terminology, holomorphic-functions

A theorem says as follows

> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on $A$. Assume that the infinite series
>   $$s(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(z)$$
>   converges locally uniformly on $A$ to a function $s:A\to\mathbb{C}$. Then $s$ is holomorphic on $A$.

I made a list, I'd like to clarify.

- From beginning, if one writes "$s(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(z)$", is it understood that the series is (pointwise) convergent to some limit function $s:A\to\mathbb{C}$?
- The conclusion, where it says that $s$ is holomorphic on $A$; is it the limit function or the series that is holomorphic? [For example, if we are dealing with a geometric series.]
- Similar to the last point; if one has two functions $g,h$ that agree on an open set $B\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, and it is known that $g$ is holomorphic on $B$, does it then imply that $h$ is holomorphic on $B$ as well, or should one check it?

Comment: If $g$ is analytic on $B$ and $h=g$ on $B$, then they are the same function on $B$.

Answer (score 1):

1) In this case, they tell you that the series converges locally uniformly at every point of $A,$ so in particular in converges at every point of $A.$  Typically, I think that if the series converges, the author says so, but if he just said that a function was given by a series on some domain, I'd take it to mean it converges at every point of that domain.

2) The function is holomorphic, as is the **sum** of the series.  I don't know what a "holomorphic series" is.

3) Yes. They're the same function on $B;$ how could one be holomorphic and the other not?

Comment: 1) Just be sure, the author chooses that the series is equal to $f$ on $A$, which basically means that the series is pointwise convergent and its limit is $f$, right? Thereafter, the author **assumes** that the series is locally uniformly convergent to $f$ on $A$. (I know that the last one implies the first one, but it is not my question) Is my understanding correct? 2) If I read somewhere saying "series represents a holomorphic function", does it mean that the (limit) sum of the series is holomorphic?

Comment: As to 2), yes, certainly.   As to 1), it's a little abstruse for me.  I would say that the sentence means the same thing if the characters $s(z) = $ are omitted.

Comment: 1) Okay, that would make sense. But, I still would like to know if my understanding were true. If you have Rudin's book (Real and complex analysis), please see Theorem 15.6. It says, "Suppose $f_n\in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$, no $f_n$ is identically $0$ in any component of $\Omega$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|1-f_n(z)|$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Then the product $f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Hence $f\in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$. [..]".

Comment: So, writing "$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(z)$" doesn't it just mean that the infinite product is pointwise convergent on $\Omega$ to some function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$? And then, the infinite product is uniformly convergent to $f$ on $\Omega$, if the infinite series in the previous comment converges locally uniformly on $\Omega$. I apologize for the long comments. I hope my thoughts are a bit clear now.